# Available Python client libraries for WFS transactions?

Tags: python, ogr, wfs-t, fiona, owslib

I am looking for a Python module to allow me to use WFS-T. Everything I found so far only supports getting data out via WFS, I need to INSERT and UPDATE.

**owslib** does not support WFS transactions (yet?), at least I could not find any signs of it.

**fiona** will never support WFS: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/104

**gdal** supports WFS-T via its **ogr** module but I heard not so great things about this API in Python (Fiona exists after all).

Should I just go ahead with ogr or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need any geospatial Python libraries. WFS-T is simply based on http requests. OGR does not support all WFS-T operations e.g no lock support according to [official OGR WFS documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html).

As long as you provide the payload, the authentication, the URL endpoint, you may just use Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to simplify calls to the WFS-T endpoint. For the parameters to provide for a WFS-T server, see the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#transaction) on this topic.

Comment: I tried writing my own WFS-T requests manually and failed horribly between versions, syntax and oddities. I absolutely do not want to write them by hand!

Comment: Just use something like OpenLayers to try on client side WFS-T requests. Get CURL queries and you got everything using http://curl.trillworks.com Not a good news, but IMO you can't really avoid some boilerplate.